# Как сделать такой топ-бар на wordpress

Tags: wordpress

есть макет для одного сайта который нужно сделать на вордпрессе
Пытался сверстать такой топ-бар, в конструкторе если создавал меню он добавлял элементы куда то еще. А в темах похожего я не нашел. **Как сверстать такой топ бар с помощью вордпресс?**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ну я бы правил header.php
Создайте меню в админке и выведите его через wp_nav_menu.

Ну а так это просто верстка обыкновенная. 
Или я вас не так понимаю?

Вот пример вывода меню:

```
<?=wp_nav_menu( [
                    'theme_location'  => '',
                    'menu'            => 'Main', 
                    'container'       => 'div', 
                    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse', 
                    'container_id'    => 'nav-list',
                    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto', 
                    'menu_id'         => '',
                    'echo'            => true,
                    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                    'before'          => '',
                    'after'           => '',
                    'link_before'     => '',
                    'link_after'      => '',
                    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s"><li class="nav-item">%3$s</li></ul>',
                    'depth'           => 0,
                    'walker'          => '',
                ] );?>
```

Comment: можно подробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: Что именно вам сконкретезировать?
Шапка в WP храниться в файле темы header.php
В ней вы и должны сверстать свой хедер.
Меню в ВП можно вывести с помощью функции wp_nav_menu, пример в интернете найдете по первой ссылке,на память не напишу.
А само меню для вывода просто создайте в админ.панели WP.